# Zip files get corrupt when uploaded to the server using Tornado

Tags: python, upload, zip, tornado

I am using the code below to upload zip files to a server. Everything works fine but the incoming zip files are corrupt for some reason. I know that the zip files are created correctly so they are not corrupt at the time of creation. Thus, there is something wrong with the server code.

In short, regular files like `.txt` are uploaded just fine but the incoming zip files are corrupt. Anyone has an idea about why this may be happening ?

```
import tornado
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import os, uuid

__UPLOADS__ = "uploads/"

class Userform(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("form.html")


class Upload(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        fileinfo = self.request.files['filearg'][0]
        fname = fileinfo['filename']
        fh = open(__UPLOADS__ + fname, 'w')
        fh.write(fileinfo['body'])
        self.finish("Success!")


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", Userform),
    (r"/upload", Upload),
    ], debug=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: have you tried opening the uploaded file destination in binary mode (i.e. 'wb')? Just a guess mind you... If that works, you may have to process content headers to process text and binary files differently (if you want to perform CR/NL processing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server is running on a Windows machine, it's because this line of code:

```
fh = open(__UPLOADS__ + fname, 'w')
```

opens the file as a text file. When you use that to create a file containing binary data, every occurrence of the value `0x0a` (newline) will be replaced with a `\n\r` pair. Change that line to

```
fh = open(__UPLOADS__ + fname, 'wb')
```

...to open that as a binary file & see what happens.

Comment: Thanks so much this indeed was the issue !